# Deploy static websites to heroku but error : "ERROR: No 'composer.lock' found!"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I am a newbie with Rails and trying to make a static website, and I tried to deploy it to heroku. Here are what I did

```
Heroku login
git init
git add .
git commit -m "My site ready for deployment."
heroku app:create herokuapp6688
```

Until there, nothing serious. But when I tried to push to heroku

```
git push heroku master
```

it said to me that I had this error

```
ERROR: No 'composer.lock' found!
A 'composer.lock' file was not found in your project, but there
is a 'composer.json' file with dependencies inside 'require'.
```

I am very confuse about this error, could you please give me some ideas? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Appears you haven't installed Composer. `composer.lock` file will be created once you install then update Composer.

1. Install Composer (refer to link below)
2. Update Composer (run "composer update" command)

Afterwards, confirm that `composer.lock` has been created. Finally, add to your git repository, commit, then push to heroku.

Steps to install Composer: https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#installation-linux-unix-macos